# Socket.io is emitting an event twice

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am emitting an event for a specific client from the server but it is emitting twice and the socket.on() method is executing twice on the react.js frontend which is ruining my project.

Server Side

```
socket.on("returning signal", payload => {
        console.log("Returning recieverd signal from "+socket.id+" to "+payload.callerID)
        io.to(payload.callerID).emit('receiving returned signal', { signal: payload.signal, id: socket.id });
});
```

Client-Side

```
user.socket.on("receiving returned signal", payload => {
        console.log("Getting receiving returned signal event");
        const item = peersRef.current.find(p => p.peerID === payload.id);
        item.peer.signal(payload.signal);
});
```

I used logs for debugging and
"Getting receiving returned signal event"
this message is printing twice on the browser console.

It's been a month so please help!!!

Comment: socket.removeListener('returning signal'); remove the listener after pal.. that's why.

Comment: you are generating multiple connections.

Comment: socket.off('MY_EVENT', doThisOnlyOnce).on('MY_EVENT', doThisOnlyOnce);